# Creating a spherical CRS in Pyproj with "R_A"

Tags: geospatial, proj, pyproj

The Proj documentation states that the `R_A` parameter indicates "A sphere with the same surface area as the ellipsoid." ([source](https://proj.org/usage/ellipsoids.html#cmdoption-arg-R_A))

So I tried this, believing I would get a spherical CRS with radius set to the WGS84 authalic radius:

```py
import pyproj

crs = pyproj.CRS(proj='latlon', R_A='WGS84')
```

But was disappointed to find that this returned some non-sphere ellipsoid with `f` not equal to 0. I also tried explicitly specifying `sphere=True`, but got the same result.

What am I misunderstanding about the docs with regard to `R_A`? And is there a straightforward way to create a spherical CRS that uses this specific radius?

Comment: It may be related to this: https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/3170. However, it may be better to ask the PROJ devs.

Comment: This might also be helpful: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/advanced_examples.html#debugging-internal-proj